# How to get screenshot of webpage using puppeteer sharp in windows server 2008

Tags: c#, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using puppeteer sharp v1.10 for getting screenshot of webpages. It is working fine in windows 10 machine but not working in **windows server 2008**.

But in puppeteer github repo, they already reported and fixed the issue by using System.Net.WebSockets.Managed. I have installed this nuget package in puppeteer demo sample. But I don't know how to getting this worked in windows server 2008.

Can anyone please help me to getting screenshot in windows server 2008 with puppeteer-sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can use System.Net.WebSockets.Managed on Puppeteer-Sharp

```
var browserOptions = new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    WebSocketFactory = (uri, socketOptions, cancellationToken)
        => System.Net.WebSockets.SystemClientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, cancellationToken)
};
using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(browserOptions))
using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
{

}
```

Comment: I already tried this code example, but getting target closed exception: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected exception.

Comment: on my further analysis I found that, it is not working only on headless mode. If I set headless to false, then it is working fine in windows server 2008. But I need to convert a webpage to pdf and image in headless mode.

Comment: @john any solution for your problem